# Making Inline for Website page content using HTML, CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Expected output:

I need first & second parapragh should be inline, which is my appropriate result.

Here what i tried in HTML:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</div> <div class="content1" style="display:inline"> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. <br>
        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
         <ul>
        <li>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
        <li>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    </ul> </div>
        <a class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">read more...</a>
```

CSS:

```
.content1{
      text-align: justify;
      
      font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 0;
line-height: 24px;
  }
  
   .content2{
      text-align: justify;
      
      font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 0;
line-height: 24px;
  }
  
  .inline{
       display: inline-block;
      
  }
```

Javascript:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content1").hide();
    $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {
        var txt = $(".content1").is(':visible') ? 'read more...' : 'read less';
        $(".show_hide").text(txt);
        $(this).prev('.content1').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
</scritp>
```

Here what i tried in Codepen:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/Shahbazmak/pen/qBbjedp)

Comment: both `content1` and `content2` in same line than breaking into next line?

Comment: Please be more precise with what you want. Isn't it inline already?

Comment: kindly check codepen which i have sent, yes it is not inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add `display:inline;` to `div`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/qr6wLx5t/61/) to validate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content1").hide();
  $(".show_hide").on("click", function() {
    var txt = $(".content1").is(':visible') ? 'read more...' : 'read less';
    $(".show_hide").text(txt);
    $(this).prev('.content1').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}

.content1,
.content2 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem </div>
<div class="content1"> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. <br> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
  type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
  recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <ul>
    <li>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">read more...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/loveshdongre/pen/GRovKJp)
Convert content1 and content2 to `span` instead of `div`

```html
<body>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <span class="content2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</span>
      <span class="content1" style="display:inline">
         when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. <br>
         when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
         <ul>
            <li>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
            <li>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
         </ul>
        </span>
      <a class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">read more...</a>
   </body>
```

Comment: I added a code pen link, see if this is the desired result you want.